# R function for extracting ESS data, "could not find function paste"

Tags: r, list, function, paste

From the "essurvey" package I have a datasett (as a "list" object) from which I'm attempting to get all ESS rounds for all countries. To do this somewhat efficiently I'm attempting to create a function that will do this for me, however I experience to problems:
Firstly, if I use the "paste" function to get names of the object I get the error:
`Error in paste: could not find function "paste<-"`.
Secondly, when attempting to set a name withing the function just to see if it would work without the paste-part, it runs without error, but also without any result. Anyone who can see a solution? All help i appreciated!

```
ESS_Load <- function(N, CC){
temp <- Data[[N]]
paste(N, CC, sep = "_") <-
subset(temp, cntry == CC)
rm(temp)


}

ESS_Load(9, "NO")
```

Comment: the syntax `paste(x, ...) <- y`  doesn't call the function `paste()`, it is actually equivalent to ``x <- `paste<-`(x, ..., value = y)``, and `paste<-` doesn't exist. It's not clear what your desired output is here as `rm(temp)` will return NULL in any case

Comment: Oh, that explains that at least, thank you! The desired output is a dataframe with the name ````CC_N```` where cc is the country code, and N is the number of the ESS round. In the Data list object all the ESS rounds are stored as dataframes, and I want each country_round to be it's own data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your comment, you want to create a dataframe named `{CC}_{N}` in your calling environment, as a side effect of your function.

This can be achieved this way:

```r
# first build sample data
set.seed(1)
Data <- list(iris[sample(nrow(iris),5),], iris[sample(nrow(iris),5),])
Data
#> [[1]]
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor
#> 129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica
#> 43           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 14           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
#> 74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor
#> 7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa

iris_Load <- function(N, CC){
  nm <- paste(CC, N, sep = "_")
  res <- subset(Data[[N]], Species == CC)
  assign(nm, res, envir = parent.frame()) # create your object with right name and value in calling environment
  invisible() # will return NULLL without printing
}

iris_Load(1, "setosa")
setosa_1
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
```

If you can afford to do the following it's arguably better practice though, functions with side effects can be surprising and are generally discouraged in most cases :

````
iris_Load <- function(N, CC){
  subset(Data[[N]], Species == CC)
}
setosa_1 <- iris_Load(1, "setosa")
setosa_1
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
```
````

Comment: Thank you, that did solve mye problem perfectly! If you have the time, could I ask why the bottom answer would be preferable? Still new to all this, so I try to learn all I can.

Comment: Sure, to know what the function affects in the first case you need to know the function, or read its code. Another user skimming through your code, or running it, won't understand right away that the object `setosa_1` has been created in the environment. The second option is much more transparent. Usually "good" functions with side effects are those that set options, open the viewer, browse a website, save a file... but creating a variable in the calling environment is not great practice because there's a clearer way to do it.

Comment: This touches the subject in more depth: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html